# hibernate: ternary association mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, hibernate-annotations

Technology Description:
Hibernate annotation- 3.4.0.GA
java 1.5

**table** : users_roles_branches
**columns** : user_id, role_id, branch_id

A user is assigned different roles for different branches of a company.

Now i have one java pojo class

```
     public class branch
     {
                @ManyToMany
             @JoinTable(name = "users_roles_branches", joinColumns = {   @JoinColumn(name="branch_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
             @MapKeyManyToMany(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", unique = false) })

                public Map<User, Role> getUserRoleMap() {
          return userRoleMap;
           }
     }
```

Basic requirement is to retrieve list of roles assigned to different users in a branch.

Problem facing: since one user can have multiple roles assigned to it, map will no work for user-role mapping data.

One solution could be Map>, but i doubt if i can use nested collection with hibernate.

Please help me out!

If question is not understandable or not in representable form please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to introduce a new concept in your domain-model `RoleAssignment`:

```
class RoleAssignment {
  private User user; 
  private Branch branch;
  private Role role;
}
```

Entities `User`, `Branch` and `Role` should have 1:N relationship with `RoleAssignment`. For eg:

```
class User { 
  private Set<RoleAssignment> roleAssignemnts;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid creating a class which is not directly mapped to an entity. Your solution is feasible but is there any other possible way avoiding creating any more classes except Role, User, Branch. Like using some collection or some wrapper of collection. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Maddy.Shik Hibernate seems to support ternary associations. Please see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ternary . Will this work for you?

Comment: @Entity
public class Company {
   @Id 
   int id;
   ...

   @OneToMany // unidirectional

   @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="employee_id")

   Map<Employee, Contract> contracts;

}                                                                 In this example, If Employee has multiple contracts it will not work, which is very much probable in ternary association.

Comment: what would the User mapping look like in this case?