# Eclipse + Hibernate + Spring question

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I can't figure out how to organize classes in project...

I need to show all Workers with their history of the specialties (types).

I have 3 tables in DB:
Workers: id, name, address
Specialty: id, description
Worker_Type: id_worker, id_specialty, hire_date

I have:

```
class Specialty
{
    ... 
}

class Worker
{
    private List<Specialty> history;
    ...
}
```

How can i map Specialty(Class) to two tables (Specialty and Worker_Specialty) to get all information about worker inculding history ?

Maybe i have to create one more class SpecialtyHistory and map it to Worker_Specialty ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing is called a ternary association, or in other words, a many-to-many relationship that includes adding information on the relationship itself. There are several approaches to mapping ternary associations, one of which being creating a SpecialtyHistory class as you mentioned, treating the relationship as a first class entity. If you did not need hire_date, you could just use a normal many-to-many mapping.

The Hibernate documentation has additional information on [ternary associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ternary).

Some previous StackOverflow questions: [hibernate: ternary association mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415260/hibernate-ternary-association-mapping) and [Ternary (and n-ary) relationships in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613347/ternary-and-n-ary-relationships-in-hibernate).